# how to format 'ls -lrt' and send to text file in bash

Tags: bash, format, printf, echo, ls

This is a simple formatting question but the answer escapes me.

I have a bash script to find certain files with a wildcard, print to file, and send in an email. I need to `ls -lrt $var*` but I can't get the output to print cleanly line by line like you see on the screen. I'm looking for this in the output file:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  14173 Nov 30 06:39 20171129_file1.txt.gz<br>
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  30954 Nov 30 06:39 20171129_file2.txt.gz<br>
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  95933 Nov 30 07:01 20171129_file3.txt.gz<br>
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 399507 Nov 30 08:43 20171129_file4.txt.gz<br>
```

I tried this:

```
for f in  `ls -ltr $var*`; do
  echo $f >> /tmp/mailtext
done
```

But the file output has a new line for every field:

```
-rw-rw-r--
1
user
user
133119
Dec
1
07:06
20171130_filename.txt.gz
etc......
```

And then I tried this, with printf, which doesn't send a new line like echo, but the four files are all jumbled together.

```
for f in `ls -ltr $var*`; do
    printf "x $f"  >> /tmp/mailtext
done
```

which produces the output all on one line:

```
x -rw-rw-r--x 1x userx userx 13318x Decx 1x 07:06x 20171130_filename1.txt.gzx -rw-rw-r--x 1x userx userx 30793x Decx 1x 07:06x 20171130_filename2.txt.gzx -rw-rw-r--x 1x userx userx 99811x Decx 1x 08:00x 20171130_filename3.txt.gzx -rw-rw-r--x 1x userx userx 41363x Decx 1x 08:10x 20171130_filename4.txt.gz
```

Of course I tried printf "x $f\n" but then it looked like the one in the first try.

So, any ideas how to do this simple formatting? Thank you!

Comment: why not `ls -ltr $var* > /tmpmailtext` ? Good luck.

Comment: [Don't try to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [don't use a `for` loop to iterate over command output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: Please use formatting in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you realised with those 2 tests, doing:

```
for i in `some command` ; do
  ...
done
```

makes some command's output be parsed and word-splitted according to the $IFS, and then i takes each of those values, one by one. In your case, it will be splitted around spaces, so each words is read one by one.

What you need is simply to redirect the command's output in a file, just do:

```
ls -lrt "$var"* > somefile
```

Notice that I add quotes around a "$var" (it's a good practice, in almost all cases), and that I leave the `*` outside those double-quotes so that the shell still interpret's it as a globbing request.

If you wanted instead to print the result line by line (with some pause in between), you can do the following:

```
for file in "$var"* ; do
  ls -lrt "$file"  # mandatory double-quotes
  sleep 1          # will sleep 1 second before looping
done | tee somefile  # shows both on your screen AND sends to "somefile"
```

or any variation thereof.

Notice here that I **do not parse the output of ls** (for exemple: the **broken** way: `ls -lrt "$var"* | whil IFS= read -r line; do ... ; done` : will not work well if any filename contains a newline, and there are other bad side  effects as well).

Instead I use directly the correct way: the for loop let's the shell put the relevant filename inside the `$file` var, one by one .

See : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls (entry 1) for a good explanation.

Comment: Ah well, yes that works, and yes I made this overcomplicated!

In my defense, I was just fixing someone else's script, and he had 

echo `ls -lrt $var*` >> file

and it was all jumbled. So I was trying to unjumble it. 

Anyway problem solved. I knew there was a simple answer! :/

Comment: @ChuckPedro: there is no shame in trying, and you learn that way :) I recommend highly you browse all the BashPitfalls, too, and also on the same site the BashGuide and BashFaq entries. Welcome to shell programming (and to this place. unix.stackexchange.com is also a good place for shell specific oddities, especially if it relates to anything unix underneath (filenames, etc).)